# How to click on webview button in Android Esspresso Kakao test

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, android-espresso

I have an html form outside my android app which part looks like this:

```
<form action="https://cards-accept.bm.pl/secure_back/play/AW2E8CY8ZG" method="POST"><div class="form-row"><label for="PaRes" data-trans="PaRes"></label><div class="form-field"><textarea id="PaRes" name="PaRes" rows="10" cols="54">&lt;dummy pareq&gt;</textarea></div></div><div class="form-row"><label for="MD">MD</label><div class="form-field"><input type="text" name="MD" id="MD" value="29cdce57-e7a1-475f-8243-b141bb2e162f" autocomplete="off"></div></div><div class="tac"><button type="submit" class="btn dark"><span>SUBMIT</span></button></div></form>
```

I need to click on the button SUBMIT in my test.
I have tried to achive that by this code, but failed:

```
      onScreen<MyScreen> {
            webView {
                withElement(Locator.CLASS_NAME, "btn dark") {
                    click()
                }
            }
        }
```

I have an exception as below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in evaluationEvaluation: status: 32 value: {message=Compound class names not permitted} hasMessage: true message: Compound class names not permitted
```

Is there a way to click on the SUBMIT button in the other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve my issue is to use `TAG_NAME`, as fortunately, I have only one `button` tag in this html present

```
     onScreen<MyScreen> {
            webView {
                withElement(Locator.TAG_NAME, "button") {
                    click()
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

using space in class names is not permitted. Space is used to assign multiple classes to a single element.

change the button class name like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn_dark">
```

and the java code to this:

```
  onScreen<MyScreen> {
            webView {
                withElement(Locator.CLASS_NAME, "btn_dark") {
                    click()
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: But I cannot change my class name in html... This is outside my android app

Comment: Try getting the button itself instead of CLASS_NAME  or get the class as an atrribute (I don't know if there is any attribute selector?)